# stanford parser can't read german umlauts

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

The stanford parser (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.html), version 3.6.0, comes with trained grammars for Engish, German and other languages. To parse german text the stanford parser provides the tool lexparser-lang.sh

```
./lexparser-lang.sh
Usage: lexparser-lang.sh lang len grammar out_file FILE...

  lang       : Language to parse (Arabic, English, Chinese, German, French)
  len        : Maximum length of the sentences to parse
  grammar    : Serialized grammar file (look in the models jar)
  out_file   : Prefix for the output filename
  FILE       : List of files to parse
```

So I call it with these options:

```
sadik@sadix:stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09$ ./lexparser-lang.sh German 500 edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz factored german_test.txt
```

The input file german_test.txt contains a single German sentence:

```
Fußball findet um 8 Uhr in der Halle statt.
```

But the "ß" results in a warning and a wrong result. Same with "ä", "ö" and "ü". Now, lexparser-lang.sh is supposed to be designed to deal with German text as input. Is there any option I am missing?

**How it is:**

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz ... 
 done [3.8 sec].
Parsing file: german_test.txt
Apr 01, 2016 12:48:45 AM edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer next
WARNING: Untokenizable:  (U+9F, decimal: 159)
Parsing [sent. 1 len. 11]: FuÃ ball findet um 8 Uhr in der Halle statt .
Parsed file: german_test.txt [1 sentences].
Parsed 11 words in 1 sentences (32.07 wds/sec; 2.92 sents/sec).
```

With a parse tree that looks like crap:

```
(S (ADV FuÃ) (ADV ball) (VVFIN findet)
  (PP (APPR um) (CARD 8) (NN Uhr))
  (PP (APPR in) (ART der) (NN Halle))
  (PTKVZ statt) ($. .))
```

**How it should be**

When written "Fussball", there is no problem (except incorrect orthography)

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz ... 
     done [3.5 sec].
    Parsing file: german_test.txt
    Parsing [sent. 1 len. 10]: Fussball findet um 8 Uhr in der Halle statt .
    Parsed file: german_test.txt [1 sentences].
    Parsed 10 words in 1 sentences (40.98 wds/sec; 4.10 sents/sec).
```

The correct tree:

```
(S (NN Fussball) (VVFIN findet)
  (PP (APPR um) (CARD 8) (NN Uhr))
  (PP (APPR in) (ART der) (NN Halle))
  (PTKVZ statt) ($. .))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo script is not running the tokenizer with the correct character set.  So if your text is pre-tokenized, you can add the option "-tokenized" and it will just use space as the token delimiter.

Also you want to tell the parser to use "-encoding ISO-8859-1" for German.

Here is the full java command (alter the one found in the .sh script):

```
java -Xmx2g -cp "./*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -maxLength 500 -tLPP edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.NegraPennTreebankParserParams -hMarkov 1 -vMarkov 2 -vSelSplitCutOff 300 -uwm 1 -unknownSuffixSize 2 -nodeCleanup 2 -writeOutputFiles -outputFilesExtension output.500.stp -outputFormat "penn" -outputFormatOptions "removeTopBracket,includePunctuationDependencies" -encoding ISO_8859-1 -tokenized -loadFromSerializedFile edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz german_example.txt
```

I get this output:

```
(NUR
  (S (NN Fußball) (VVFIN findet)
    (PP (APPR um) (CARD 8) (NN Uhr))
    (PP (APPR in) (ART der) (NN Halle) (ADJA statt.))))
```

UPDATED AGAIN:

Make sure to separate "statt." into "statt ." since we are now saying the tokens are white space separated.  If we apply this fix we get this parse:

```
(S (NN Fußball) (VVFIN findet)
  (PP (APPR um) (CARD 8) (NN Uhr))
  (PP (APPR in) (ART der) (NN Halle))
  (PTKVZ statt) ($. .))
```

So just to summarize, basically the issue is we need to tell the PTBTokenizer to use ISO_8859-1 and LexicalizedParser to use ISO_8859-1.

I would recommend just using the full pipeline to accomplish this.

1. Download Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 from here:

   http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/
2. Download the German model jar from here:

   http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
3. Run this command:

   ```
   java -Xmx3g -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*:stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models-german.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties -file german_example_file.txt -outputFormat text
   ```

This will tokenize and parse the text and use the correct character encoding.

Comment: interesting to see that the result is not really good. In fact wrong. Last word should be (PTKVZ statt).

Comment: Ok so I just added instructions for using the full pipeline this will handle the tokenizing and the parsing and will handle the characters correctly.